# Webpack file loader outputs empty png images

Tags: node.js, webpack

I run into a very weird problem when I try to use file loader.

```
 var sunTextureUrl = require("file?name=picture.png!../textures/flare.png");
 console.log(sunTextureUrl);
```

My config is like this

```
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.glsl$/, loader: 'webpack-glsl'},
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader", query: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendors', filename: "vendors.js"}),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(minifiedOpt),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(opt.production ? 'production' : 'development')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          THREE: 'three'
        })
    ]
```

I get the following output:

```
                               Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
c8510617bc54cb2c5b707a4dfdb98337.png   13.2 kB          [emitted]
                         picture.png  82 bytes          [emitted]
                             main.js   12.5 kB       0  [emitted]  main
                          vendors.js    491 kB       1  [emitted]  vendors
```

In browser, the console.log gives me

```
/assets/picture.png
```

So basically, webpack parses a single image to two. And the one with the hash as name is the image I want, and the picture.png is an empty image. Very strange.

Comment: seems like chunks issue, going thru chunks plugin

Comment: Hi, I added my plugins to the code above. I tried commenting out the chunk plugins as well as all the plugins. It still gives the same thing.

Comment: Hey @Flmhdfj, I'm facing the same issue. Did you found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In your above snippet, the loader referenced appears to be `file`. Should it not be `file-loader`?

```
{ test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
```

FWIW, in my case, I had two conflicting rules:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
    },
  ],
},
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 8192,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

`file-loader` above was redundant as `url-loader` will fall back to `file-loader` beyond the limit. So I removed the `file-loader` rule.